# LeetCode problem number 8. String to Integer (atoi) with JS

Tags: javascript

I have create the following JavaScript function

```
var myAtoi = function(s) {
    if(s.length > 200) return 
    const reg = s.replace(/-\D/g, '');
    let num = parseInt(reg)
    if(s.includes("-+")) return 0
    if((isNaN(num))) return 0
    if(s>2147483648) return 2147483647
    if(s<-2147483648) return -2147483648
    return num
};
```

It fail a testcase  :

- input = "2147483648"
- output = 2147483648
- expected = 2147483647

Comment: use => at if(s=>2147483648)

Comment: change `if (s > 2147483648)` to `if ( num >= 2147483648)` also `if (s <-2147483648)` by `if ( num <= -2147483648)`.

Comment: @MisterJojo Is it `=>` and `=<` or `>=` and `<=`?

Comment: Thanks for fixing your comment

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if(s>2147483648) return 2147483647
```

By

```
if(s>=2147483648) return 2147483647
```

Also if you want to include -2147483648 in your testcase

replace

```
if(s<-2147483648) return -2147483648
```

by

```
if(s<=-2147483648) return -2147483648
```

**the Testcase**

```js
// Online Javascript Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your Javascript code using JS Online Compiler
var myAtoi = function(s) {
    if(s.length > 200) return 
    const reg = s.replace(/-\D/g, '');
    let num = parseInt(reg)
    if(s.includes("-+")) return 0
    if((isNaN(num))) return 0
    if(s>=2147483648) return 2147483647
    if(s<-2147483648) return -2147483648
    return num
};

console.log(myAtoi ("2147483648"));
```

- input = "2147483648"
- output = 2147483647

Comment: I think you want `>=`, not `=>`. Otherwise it's "if function is truthy, return 'value'."

Comment: @DarrylNoakes yes i don't paid attention because  i write fast